# Give priority for one class If html div have two class

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
html+='<div class="CardBack jewels" id="deck1"></div>'
```

From this html div I want to show the CardBack class.But it show the jewels class.How I show the CardBack class?

Comment: does you properties defined in cardback overrided by jewels? then use !important to give priority

Comment: use `!important` in front of each of the style you put in the `CardBack` class.

Answer (score 0):

The below two ways would be your best bet if you have competing classes:

Example Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhvLJ/1/

1. The second style in the stylesheet will get priority
2. Use the !important

   ```
   .CardBack{
       color: red !important
   }

   .jewels{
        color: blue;
   }
   ```

See [this link](http://www.quora.com/In-what-order-do-CSS-definitions-take-priority) for more information:

Answer (score 0):

Use CardBack twice  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aBKvg/)

```
html+='<div class="CardBack jewels" id="deck1"></div>'


.CardBack.CardBack {


}

.jewels{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class name twice like:

`.CardBack.CardBack { //all the stylesin here for CardBack class }`

Hope it helps! :)